# Include youtube api in opensource project

Tags: vb.net, youtube-api

I'm developing an opensource software  (using vb.net) and part of the program uploads a video to youtube.
I want to include the youtube api to accomplish this but I don't want to include my private developer key.
Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python, you can create a Config file using ConfigParser and explicitly state in your README that the user needs to insert his developer key for the code to work. 
Something  similar can be achieved in VB.net using  imports.

Just remember to keep your Config files separate from the rest. 
Many sites whose source is open (Like reddit) use Config files for similar purposes so that the security of the site isn't threatened despite being open source.